# Oracle procedure with SYS_REFCURSOR as OUT parameter displays only old values

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I created the following table called APP_USERS with nine columns:

[image]

I want to get all data from a single record by calling a procedure with SYS_REFCURSOR as OUT parameter: The code looks like that:

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY USER_LOGIN AS  
    PROCEDURE getUserToLogIn(comp_id NUMBER, user_id APP_USERS.USER_ID%TYPE, pass APP_USERS.ACC_PASSWORD%TYPE, v_IS_ADMIN IN char, 
        curs out sys_refcursor)
        IS 
        lala APP_USERS%ROWTYPE;
    BEGIN 
        OPEN curs FOR
        SELECT USER_ID,FIRST_NAME,MIDDLE_NAME,LAST_NAME,SEX,COMPANY_ID,IS_ADMIN,ACC_PASSWORD,IS_ACTIVE 
        FROM APP_USERS
        WHERE COMPANY_ID = comp_id and USER_ID = TRIM(user_id) and ACC_PASSWORD = pass and IS_ADMIN = v_IS_ADMIN;
        
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(comp_id);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(user_id);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(pass);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_IS_ADMIN);
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('--------------------------------------');
        
        LOOP
            FETCH curs INTO lala;
            exit when curs%notfound;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(lala.USER_ID);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(lala.COMPANY_ID);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(lala.ACC_PASSWORD);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(lala.IS_ADMIN);
        END LOOP;
        CLOSE curs;
    END getUserToLogIn; 
END USER_LOGIN;
```

At first I called a procedure by running a simple anonymous block like below:

```
declare
curs sys_refcursor;
begin
USER_LOGIN.getUserToLogIn(1000,'EU1002','UCFE3M0N','N',curs);
end;
```

and I got the following results:

[image]

Next time I run the anonymous block again with wrong data, so that the procedure could not find them, but the result was not correct:

[image]

At first time, when I entered correct data my procedure displayed them, but the second attempt with wrong data entered caused displaying the data from the previous one.
My question is why:

```
exit when curs%notfound;
```

is this part of the code overlooked?

Comment: That;s not quite correct. you should just be opening curs in your procedure and have the caller loop through it and close it.

Comment: Can You explain it by changing my code?

Answer (score 0):

That not the proper way to use a refcursor.  Here is a simplified example from your code:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE getUserToLogIn( user_id APP_USERS.USER_ID%TYPE,
         curs  in out sys_refcursor)
 IS 
   BEGIN 
       OPEN curs FOR  SELECT * FROM APP_USERS; -- where blah, blah
  end ;


    declare
           lala APP_USERS%ROWTYPE;
           my_cursor sys_refcursor;
    begin        
            getUserToLogIn('xxx', my_cursor);
        LOOP
                FETCH my_cursor INTO lala;
                exit when my_cursor%notfound;
                DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('output= ' || lala.USER_ID);
        end loop;
        close my_cursor;
    end;
```

So the standard method is you call the procedure that creates the SELECT statement you need, then just OPEN cursor parameter.  The caller then gets the cursor back, iterates thought it, then closes it.
[Heres](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/using-ref-cursors-to-return-recordsets) also a tutorial.